# Swing jfilechooser blocking other frames after passing null

Tags: java, swing

I want my jfilechooser to display without blocking parent but i tried everything and still it is blocking parent. Any Solution....

```
public class main_class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame parent_frame = new JFrame("PARENT");

        if (parent_frame != null) {
            parent_frame.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 500);
            parent_frame.setVisible(true);
            parent_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            int returnVal = chooser.showDialog(null, "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `showDialog` will use a modal dialog.

`JFileChooser` is simply based on a `JComponent`, so, so long as you don't mind that your  code won't block, you could add the `JFileChooser` to a frame/dialog that you can yourself.

Comment: I dont want to add jfilechooser with any jframe or i dont want to use modality behavior of jfilechooser can it be possible.

Comment: I have also passed parent_frame in jfilechooser and still parent_frame is blocked by jfilechooser i want it enabled and independent from jfilechooser

Comment: The only way to achieve this would be to make your own dialog. But, this means you lose the modality behaviour, meaning, your code won't wait for the dialog to be dismissed before continuing.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment makes me sense to me :( - perhaps you'd like to take a read of [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Comment: Is there any easy way to create custom jfilechooser.

Comment: Is there an easy way, no not really. You could try extending JFileChooser and overriding the showDialog methods, implementing your own logic, but it would render the return result useless

Comment: I tried that one and createdialog function and showdialog i inherited it is creating dialog properly but then i dont have button click listner for that so when ever i am clicking on any button it is not doing anything.

Comment: You will need to create your own dialog, with it's own buttons and place the file chooser component on it